# Broadcasting video stream using rtsp from pi zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian, rtsp, rtsp-client

I have set up the RTSP server.Video is broadcasting but I am not getting the video stream on my pc.

I had first installed Gstreamer camera source

```
git clone https://github.com/thaytan/gst-rpicamsrc.git
cd gst-rpicamsrc
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Then I installed the GSTREAM RTSP server lib.

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server
cd gst-rtsp-server
git checkout 1.4
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Then I am starting broadcasting by this command

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rpicamsrc preview=false bitrate=2000000 keyframe-interval=15 ! video/x-h264, framerate=15/1 ! h264parse ! fakesink silent=false
```

And finally from the test example I am running the thing like

```
./test-launch "( rpicamsrc preview=false bitrate=2000000 keyframe-interval=15 ! video/x-h264, framerate=15/1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

but the thing is when I try to open the stream in vlc it is not showing up any thing.

Comment: Just to make sure. Is the `gst-launch-1.0` command still running while you run the second one? The first one would block the cam to be available for the second.. Also what RTSP URL do you put into VLC?